# How to view or sync an iDoneThis calendar in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, tasks

[iDoneThis](http://www.idonethis.com/) is a great web app to keep track of your daily tasks.

I was wondering if there is a way to view your iDoneThis calendar in Google Calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your iDoneThis calendar are three links: Share, Feed, and Invite. Click on Feed and turn on the secret link. You will be given a link, and this is what you feed into Google Calendar. Now just follow http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37100 to feed your iDoneThis into them.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea, but it doesn't appear that they have any kind of [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api) or [iCalendar feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) for your calendar.  So unfortunately, no -- there isn't a way to do this.

Sad panda.